# Master and GH-Pages are set up, now what?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I had an old github-page that had a custom url and it pointed to my master branch
So I decided to set up development and production branch, Master being the development and gh-pages being production.

Now the build process works, and finished content from master and getting pushed to gh-pages, but the site isn't updating.

I have my CNAME file and the DNS setting all configured correctly, since they were working when  I only had master branch. But now that I've moved everything to gh-pages, things are propagating.

Do I have to update the DNS records at all? Any tips or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike, as you repository is a user repository (userName.github.io scheme) the production code MUST be in the **master** branch.

You also have a DNS problem. A dig gives :

```
dig yoursite.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd

yoursite.com.           1570  IN    CNAME   mhartington.github.io.
yoursite.github.io.     3370  IN    CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  20    IN    A   23.235.43.133
```

It is supposed to give :

```
yoursite.com.       73  IN  A   192.30.252.154
yoursite.com.       73  IN  A   192.30.252.153
```

As you can read in the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider) :

- remove CNAMEs records
- set two A records pointing to 192.30.252.154 and 192.30.252.153
- wait for propagation

Comment: Well the addition CNAME record was for a custom url, but thanks!

Comment: @mhartington glad to see http://mikehartington.com/ running and to discover Ionic.